# Custom Close Button for Chrome Custom Tab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possible to override the behaviour of the default close button on custom chrome tabs in Android? For example instead of just closing the chrome tab, can we redirect to a new Activity, or launch a dialog?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do that. You can try to start the CustomTabIntent for result and wait for it finish and start it from `onActivityResult()` based on the `requestCode` you have started it with.

```
  private void openUrlForResult(CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent, String url, int requestCode){
        customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivityForResult(customTabsIntent.intent, requestCode);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that helped. Although my problem turned out to be a lot more simpler.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share it with us?

Comment: you can also use onRestart() of parent Activity

Comment: awesome solution , had been banging my head for quiet sometime for this